# Whats app doesn't support Webview android

Tags: android, webview, whatsapp

I want to use whats app in Webview android. I've already tried to set user agent but it didn't help.
Is there any way that whats app recognize webview as Chrome browser.

```
String newUA= "";
        newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.181 Safari/537.36";

        binding.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        binding.webView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
        binding.webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set User Agent BEFORE calling URL load (make all settings-related calls before any page load try)

Comment: Not work agein @snachmsm